# The difference between update, updateOne and updateMany functions in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am a little confused about these mongoose functions:
update, updateOne, and updateMany.

can someone clarify what is the difference between them.

updateMany: updates all the documents that match the filter.

updateOne: updates only one documnet that match the filter.

what about the update?

Comment: Hi Heybat, be aware `update` method is being depreacated by mongoose, "Replace update() with updateOne(), updateMany(), or replaceOne()" see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Model.updateMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany)

> Same as `update()`, except MongoDB will update all documents that match filter (as opposed to just the first one) regardless of the value of the `multi` option.

- [Model.updateOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne)

> Same as `update()`, except it does not support the `multi` or `overwrite` options.

Take a look at the source code of these three methods:

`update`:

```js
Model.update = function update(conditions, doc, options, callback) {
  _checkContext(this, 'update');

  return _update(this, 'update', conditions, doc, options, callback);
};
```

`updateMany`:

```js
Model.updateMany = function updateMany(conditions, doc, options, callback) {
  _checkContext(this, 'updateMany');

  return _update(this, 'updateMany', conditions, doc, options, callback);
};
```

`updateOne`:

```js
Model.updateOne = function updateOne(conditions, doc, options, callback) {
  _checkContext(this, 'updateOne');

  return _update(this, 'updateOne', conditions, doc, options, callback);
};
```

They call the `_update` function with different `op` parameter finally.

`_update`:

```js
/*!
 * Common code for `updateOne()`, `updateMany()`, `replaceOne()`, and `update()`
 * because they need to do the same thing
 */

function _update(model, op, conditions, doc, options, callback) {
  const mq = new model.Query({}, {}, model, model.collection);

  callback = model.$handleCallbackError(callback);
  // gh-2406
  // make local deep copy of conditions
  if (conditions instanceof Document) {
    conditions = conditions.toObject();
  } else {
    conditions = utils.clone(conditions);
  }
  options = typeof options === 'function' ? options : utils.clone(options);

  const versionKey = get(model, 'schema.options.versionKey', null);
  _decorateUpdateWithVersionKey(doc, options, versionKey);

  return mq[op](conditions, doc, options, callback);
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/04dd2be13dee1311c121ba1a099a773de6a1df49/lib/model.js#L3762)